# How can I access a variable declared in another file in python? (Not OOP)

Tags: python, flask

I'm used to object oriented programming, dependency injection, etc.  That said, I'm having trouble dealing with flask, and moving some objects around that need near global access.  I have my routes segregated to a file called `WebServer.py`.  I have a `Main.py` which serves as the entry point for the application.

Main.py:

```
x = "test"

import WebServer

# WSGI entry point
def main():
    return WebServer.app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from DebugWebServer import DebugWebServer
    server = DebugWebServer()
    server.run(WebServer.app)
```

WebServer.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    global x
    print(x)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`x` is not accessible in the index route, even if I note that it's global.

I have little experience with global variables, but I thought this would work.  Does anyone know how I can make objects instantiated in `Main.py` accessible to `WebServer.py`?

Answer (score 3):

Circular dependencies are bad.  Your `main` should pass `x` as a parameter to your `WebServer` code rather than having `WebServer` import `main` to get it for itself.

Comment: Yes that would seem ideal, but WebServer isn't a class (because it's flask).  How can I pass a parameter to it?

Answer (score 2):

Python's notion of "global" really means "module level" - there's NO process-wide global namespace, and the goal of the `global` keyword is only to allow rebinding of module-level variables from within a function (which is still considered bad practice unless there's really no other solution, which is rarely the case).

Also, you should particularily not use globals (I mean mutable globals) in a wsgi app - those apps are typically served (on production) as long-running processes in a multi-process pool, and any of the processes (usually the first inactive one) will serve a given request, so your mutable global state 1/ will affect all requets served by this process and 2/ will not be shared between different processes. So if you want to share state between processes, you use either sessions (for volatile data) or a proper database (for peristant data).

wrt/ globals, as a general rule, you can usually avoid them with plain simple well known programming features: functions arguments, functions return values, and (if you have state to share between function calls that are not directly adjacents) classes.

Now if your variable is some **readonly** configuration variable (which is ok - there's no issue with this), the proper solution in your case here is to create a distinct config module and import it where needed, ie

config.py:

```
# naming convention: use ALL_UPPER for pseudo-constants
X = 42
```

webserver.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import Response

import config

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(config.X)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

main.py

```
# note that this is your module, not the WebServer.WebServer class
# following naming conventions (module names should be all_lower)
# helps avoiding this kind of confusions

import WebServer

# contrived example, just to find a use for `config.X` here
import config
print("in main, config.X = {}".format(config.X)

# WSGI entry point
def main():
    return WebServer.app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from DebugWebServer import DebugWebServer
    server = DebugWebServer()
    server.run(WebServer.app)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is for an embedded application that will be serving a single process, and multiple threads.  But I think you hit upon the best solution for my case.  The objects I need shared would mostly be factory pattern types.  I don't need to "pass" them from main.  I can request them from a factory provider.  No more circular dependency.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, they'll be Singleton classes, so even easier

Answer (score 1):

You want to import the `x` variable from the `Main` module.

```
from Main import x
```

Comment: This answer is about the worse possible suggestion - wildcard imports are evil and so are circular dependencies, and none of this is actualy necessary.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is it ok now?

Comment: The downvotes you got were before your edits.  This seems to work.  I can't say if it's the best way, but it works.

Comment: You still have a circular dependency

Comment: @Dave it "works" for some definition of "kind of seem to work". It's still a bad solution. CF my answer as to why, and how to avoid this.